# Reshaping a data frame from wide to long in R

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have the following data frame with temperature and pressure data from 3 sensors:

```
df <- data.frame(
         Test = 1:10, 
         temperature_sensor1=rnorm(10,25,5), 
         temperature_sensor2 = rnorm(10,25,5), 
         temperature_sensor1 = rnorm(10,25,5), 
         pressure_sensor1 = rnorm(10,10,2),
         pressure_sensor2 = rnorm(10,10,2), 
         pressure_sensor3 = rnorm(10,10,2))
```

How can I reshape it into the long format, such that each row has temperature and pressure data for a single sensor

```
Test Sensor Temperature Pressure
```

Thanks!

Comment: or `gather` in `dplyr` package

Comment: Hi guys, can you please give an example? I can't figure it out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This problem is more complex than the supposed duplicate because it has two sets of columns whereas the one referenced as a supposed duplicate only has one set.

Comment: See [`melt.data.table`](https://rdrr.io/rforge/data.table/man/melt.data.table.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of approaches:

**1) dplyr/tidyr**  Convert `df` to long form using `gather` and then separate the generated `variable` column by underscore into two columns.  Finally convert from long to wide based on the `variable` column (which contains the strings `pressure` and `temperature` and `value` column (which contains the number):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   gather("variable", "value", -Test) %>% 
   separate(variable, c("variable", "sensor"), sep = "_") %>%
   spread(variable, value)
```

**2)** Can use `reshape`.  No packages needed.  The line marked optional removes the row names.  It could be omitted if that does not matter.

```
unames <- grep("_", names(df), value = TRUE)

varying <- split(unames, sub("_.*", "", unames))
sensors <- unique(sub(".*_", "", unames))

long <- reshape(df, dir = "long", varying = varying, v.names = names(varying),
         times = sensors, timevar = "sensor")
rownames(long) <- NULL # optional
```

If `df` has fixed columns then we could simplify the above a bit by hard coding `varying` and `sensors` using these definitions in place of the more complex but general code above:

```
varying <- list(pressure = 2:4, temperature = 5:7)
sensors <- c("sensor1", "sensor2", "sensor3")
```

**Note:**  To create `df` reproducibly we must set the seed first because random numbers were used so to be definite we created `df` like this.  Also note that in the question `temperature_sensor1` was used on two columns and we assumed that the second occurrence was intended to be `temperature_sensor3`.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
         Test = 1:10, 
         temperature_sensor1=rnorm(10,25,5), 
         temperature_sensor2 = rnorm(10,25,5), 
         temperature_sensor3 = rnorm(10,25,5), 
         pressure_sensor1 = rnorm(10,10,2),
         pressure_sensor2 = rnorm(10,10,2), 
         pressure_sensor3 = rnorm(10,10,2))
```